# How do I set a respawn angle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm creating a mini game map and I have a problem trying to make it so that when I respawn I face a certain angle. I tried the following command without success:

`/execute ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:emerald_block 0 /spawnpoint @p ~ ~ ~ 180.0 0.0`

How can I make it so that when I respawn I face a particular angle?

Comment: How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Hey I made some small edits to your question (they may still be in the edit queue) to make it a bit clearer/easier to read, if you feel that I have changed your question too much feel free to revert.

Answer (score 1):

So far I haven't found a way to make the spawn point command set an orientation, However you could allow a few more commands which would make the player spawn and then immediately turn to face a different direction:

**New commands in a looping command block:**

```
/execute ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:emerald_block 0 /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:command_block 1 replace {auto:0b,Command:tp @p[r=2,] ~ ~1 ~ [ ]}
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone_pressure_plate 1 replace
```

This way every time they die they will activate the command block and this will also mark checkpoints as taken as an added bonus, there are other methods using scoreboards and allot of commands and an armour stand but it would go on for too long here.